# If a character with the Polearm Master feat teleports into a space within reach of an enemy, can they make an opportunity attack upon arrival?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack, teleportation

I have a character that can swap locations with another via teleportation as an action. (Specifically, it is the [UA Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)'s [Transposition](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=23) effect from the [Nomadic Step](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=22) discipline, but the [School of Conjuration wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofConjuration)'s [Benign Transposition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#BenignTransposition-422) feature (PHB, p. 116) is almost the same.)

Another character has the equivalent of the Polearm Master feat. If the teleporter swaps locations with the Polearm Master on the teleporter's turn, and an enemy is within range, does the Polearm Master get to use his opportunity attack on the enemy when he arrives?

Comment: ...What do you mean by "the equivalent of the Polearm Master feat"?

Comment: @V2Blast I would assume he means something like "a ring that grants the benefit of the Polearm Master feat", and so I would treat this question as if he had the feat. It's probably better if OP clarifies, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, this does not work.

The reasoning is largely identical to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110203/62294) by user [keithcurtis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28927/keithcurtis), so I will not reinvent the wheel:

> From the section on opportunity attacks:
>
> > You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you
> > can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you
> > use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking
> > creature. The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s movement,
> > occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.
>
> "Creature moves", "provoking creature", and "interrupts the provoking creature's movement", all support the position that the intent of opportunity attacks is to react to another creature's movement, not your own. This is further clarified in the subsequent paragraph to mean "voluntary movement".
>
> If the intent of Polearm Master was to subvert the general rule with a specific one, it would be clearly stated, as in "This is an exception to the general rule on opportunity attacks, in that it does not require movement on the part of the target". The phrases "enters your reach" and "moves into your reach" are--barring any explicit wording to the contrary, pretty clearly synonymous. A relative movement interpretation does not match anything else in the book, unless it is clearly described as such.
>
> In short, "Enter" is an active verb, and had Polearm Mastery" been intended to break of the general rule, it would certainly have been pointed out by the designers in errata, interviews, tweets or Sage Advice.
>
> In the absence of anything like that, the general rule interpretation should apply.

Your situation is the same as the situation described above, except you're teleporting instead of walking.

Specific to our situation, observe the rules for opportunity attacks:

> You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.

Teleporting *away* from someone doesn't provoke an opportunity attack, so teleporting *toward* someone certainly does not either.